# Last step in $\nabla_z f(x,y,z), \partial_y f(x,y,z)\le c(1+|y|^{p-1}+|z|^{p-1})$ imply $ f(x,y,z)\le c(1+|y|^p+|z|^p)$

Tags: analysis, partial-differential-equations, calculus-of-variations, functional-inequalities

Let $\Omega \subset  \mathbb{R}^n$ open and bounded with Lipschitz boundary $\partial \Omega$
and the functional

$$I(u)=\int_\Omega f(x,u(x),\nabla u(x))dx$$  with $f: \bar\Omega\times\mathbb{R}\times \mathbb{R}^n  \to\mathbb{R}$ of class $C^1$

$f$ satisfies the following grow conditions:

$\partial_y f(x,y,z)\le c(1+|y|^{p-1}+|z|^{p-1}) \tag{4.5}$

$\nabla_z f(x,y,z)\le c(1+|y|^{p-1}+|z|^{p-1}), \forall (x,y,z) \in \bar\Omega\times\mathbb{R}\times \mathbb{R}^n \tag{4.5},$

for some $1<p<\infty$ and a constant $c >0$

Consider $u \in W^{1,p}(\Omega)$ in the class of functions $\Phi=\{u \in W^{1,p}(\Omega): u-g \in W^{1,p}_0(\Omega) \}$ with $g \in W^{1,p}(\Omega)$ given

**I want to prove the following theorem the conditions (4.5) imply that**

$f(x,y,z)\le c(1+|y|^p+|z|^p), \forall (x,y,z) \in \bar\Omega\times\mathbb{R}\times \mathbb{R}^n \tag{4.4},$ for some $1<p<\infty$ and a constant $c >0$ .

[image]

I did as instructed and bounded the integral using the triangle inequality, (4.5) and Young's inequality and  I got this:
$$|f(x,y,z)|\le |f(x,0,0)|+c(1+|y|^p+|z|^p)$$

**I just don't know how to get rid of $|f(x,0,0)|$ term. Any idea ?**

---

Edit. The problem is just following analogous steps to what was done in the begining of the chapter. Here it is:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: where is the estimate $4.6 ?$

Comment: @dezdichado I put a picture of the whole section, but I believed it was not relevant for the question. They just reference it to say that the estimates are the same: use Young's inequality and the equations (4.5)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the part people sometimes ignore is the given conditions. You are given the domain of $x$ variable as $\Omega$ which is open and bounded. $f$ itself is also continuously differentiable, meaning that $f$ is bounded, say by $C$ ,on $\overline{\Omega}.$ Therefore,
$$|f|\leq C + c(1+|y|^p + |z|^p)\leq c'(1+|y|^p + |z|^p) $$
with $c' = c + C.$

Comment: Why does $f$ continuously differentiable implies $f$ is bounded? It does not say over the closure.

Comment: I take it back, it is over the closure. So that is why, right? It wouldn't work for an open set

Comment: Does $\Omega$ bounded matters for this?

Comment: @some_math_guy that makes it easier. With boundedness, you get a compact domain when you include the boundary and a continuous function is bounded on a compact domain is a simple calculus result. It might be possible to relax some conditions but I am a bit rusty to remember anything off the top of my head.

Comment: Thank you, One more question if you don't mind since you're looking at the whole section. As it is written there is not reason to think that that p in equations (4.4) and (4.5) is the same fixed p of the space we are working in: $W^{1,p}(\Omega)$  but that is some other fixed p not necessarily the same. It says for "some p"

Comment: I think this should have been worded differently or use another letter because it seems that  what is consider in the rest of the section is that it is indeed the same p since we use it in (4.4) to say that the functional is well-defined if u is in $W^{1,p}(\Omega)$ because (4.4) is the integrand in the $W^{1,p}(\Omega)$ norm of u that is finite by assumption. What do you think?

Comment: $p$ is the same fixed $p$ throughout the document. Some things like Young inequality is true for all $p > 1$ sure but that's not important, but its truthfulness in other dimensions is irrelevant.

Comment: My point is that if they say (4.5) holds for some p, it can be for instance p=4. And if I am working in $W^{1,2}$ I can not use it to say that it implies $u \in W^{1,2}$

Comment: @some_math_guy But you're not (necessarily) working in $W^{1,2}$ but in $W^{1,p}$ where the $p$ is from the growth condition, so all is fine.